# How to store strings with whitespaces to databases and retrieve them for URL?

Tags: database, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I have Shops stored in a Postgreql database, I retrieve them from the frontend and use them as a link. However, since there is whitespace in them the URL looks like this `/New%20Shop`. I don't know what the right solution is, I can trim the string on the frontend link part but that can result in me not being able to query search the shop since there is whitespace at the database part. I can also change the database so that it holds the strings with whitespace with an underscore and replace the underscores with whitespace on the frontend part. These are the solutions that came to my mind however I would love to learn the right approach for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%20` is how a white space is encoded in [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

There is no single "right way" no handle mapping URLs to objects, but most apps will store a "slug" in the database which is a URL-safe version of the name (or just use a numeric id).  You would use the slug to lookup the matching entity.  Typically it is all lowercase with spaces replaced by `-` and other punctuation marks removed.  There are plenty of packages and helper functions that can convert special characters, like letters with accent marks, to their plain versions. For example, you can combine [`deburr`](https://lodash.com/docs/#deburr) and [`kebabCase`](https://lodash.com/docs/#kebabCase) from Lodash.

```js
const slugify = (title) => {
  return _.kebabCase(_.deburr(title));
}

console.log(slugify("New Shop")); // logs "new-shop"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```